# how do i set expire time to hours or minutes in Cookie and Vue-persist? Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, js-cookie

```js
const vuexCookie = new VuexPersist({
  restoreState: (key, storage) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
  saveState: (key, state, storage) => Cookies.set(key, state, {
    expires: 3
  }),
  modules: ['user'] // only save user module
})
```

How do i set the expires object to seconds or minutes?

I do not understand what the 3 means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a number, the `expires` means **days**.

> I do not understand what the 3 means

So:

```js
Cookies.set(key, state, {
  expires: 3
})
```

Means the cookie will expire in **3 days**.

> How do i set the expires object to seconds or minutes?

You [**can use a `Date`**](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#expire-cookies-in-less-than-a-day) object:

```js
var inFifteenMinutes = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
    expires: inFifteenMinutes
});
```

Or set a fraction of a day:

```js
var in30Minutes = 1/48;
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {
    expires: in30Minutes
});
```